# Bad code readability when using callbacks for network async receiving data

Tags: c++, network-programming

I'm developing the client protocol in C++ using my own network library.
I created the method for asynchronous receiving data from server.
It's method gets callback to call when data receives.
But I need to call async reading data nested in this callbacks.

Example:

```
this->Send(some_data1, some_data_length1);

this->AsyncReceive([some_data2, some_data_length2]() {
    this->Send(some_data3, some_data_length3);

    this->AsyncReceive([some_data4, some_data_length4]() {
        this->Send(some_data5, some_data_length5);

        this->AsyncReceive([some_data6, some_data_length6]() {
            this->Send(some_data7, some_data_length7);

            this->AsyncReceive([some_data8, some_data_length8]() {
                this->Send(some_data9, some_data_length9);
                
                // and more..
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Maybe somebody knows how can I solve that problem?

Comment: Rule is simple split code into smaller functions/methods. My personal rule is that lambda is always a one liner calling more complex function/method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since this is tagged C++, make your API function accept a wide range of data range rather than the old C idom of pointer + length.
Make it possible for the user code to be as wild as the following:

```cpp
std::vector<unsigned char> v;
std::array<unsigned char, 42> a;
std::string str;
std::span<int> s;
// ...
your_api.Send(v);
your_api.Send(a);
your_api.Send(str);
your_api.Send(s);
```

This will improve usability greatly. Then, add a function to your API so the user code can look like:

```cpp
your_api.Send(data);
your_api.AsyncReceiveAndSend([](auto inbound) {
   // ...
   return outboud;
}).AsyncReceiveAndSend([](auto inbound) {
   // ...
   return outboud;
}).AsyncReceive([](auto inbound) {
   // ...
})
```